# Implementing a Lottie JSON animation into PyQt5

Tags: pyqt5, lottie

I am working on a PyQt5 application and I want to bring in a Lottie JSON animation into it. I have searched far and wide but I could only find results like **convert Lottie JSON to GIF/MP4**. But thats not what I really want.
I found [something](https://www.qt.io/blog/2019/03/08/announcing-qtlottie) from the Qt website.

I assume that some changes must be made in above code and then must be implemented as a *style sheet* in PyQt5. But I am completely new to StyleSheets

Can someone give a short example of implementation of Lottie JSON into PyQt5?

EDIT 1:
According to a comment posted by @musicamante it is said that Qt uses QML for Lottie. I found this [example usage](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-lottieqt-lottieanimation.html). Can someone give a short Python implementation of it?

Comment: "must be implemented as a style sheet in PyQt5": this has absolutely nothing to do with style sheets, nor with [Qt style sheets](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet.html), which are used to style QWidgets using a predefined [set of properties](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html). Lottie works on Qt through QML (as the post you linked explains), so you need to learn how to use that first.

Comment: About your edit: sorry but this is not the scope of StackOverflow. We provide answers to specific code/programming questions, this is not a howto or tutorial website, and providing "an example code" is highly discouraged in these situations. I recommend you to begin to study QML and how to use it in Python, so that you will learn how it works and you'll be able to achieve what you want with more awareness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following must be taken into account:

- QtLottie only supports some features (at least in Qt5, see [this](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtlottie.git/tree/src/unsupported_features.txt?h=5.15.2) for more information)
- PyQt5 does not provide QtLottie by default.

For the last, because QtLottie is only focused on QML, then it is not necessary to create a binding for Python but to copy the binaries. The first thing is to know the version of Qt with which PyQt5 was compiled:

```
python -c "from PyQt5.QtCore import QT_VERSION_STR; print('Qt version', QT_VERSION_STR)"
```

In the case of PyQt5 5.15.4 it was compiled with Qt 5.15.2.

To get the Qt binaries you can use aqtinstall and download qtlottie (the following command is for linux).

```
python -m pip install aqtinstall
python -m aqt install --outputdir Qt 5.15.2 linux desktop -m qtlottie
```

To know the folder where to copy the following command must be executed:

```
python -c "from pathlib import Path; import PyQt5; print(Path(PyQt5.__file__).resolve().parent / 'Qt5')"
```

which we will call PyQt5_DIR.

So you should copy file "Qt/5.15.2/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Bodymovin.so.5.15.2" to "PyQt5_DIR/lib/libQt5Bodymovin.so.5" and the folder "Qt/5.15.2/gcc_64/qml/Qt/labs/lottieqt" to "PyQt5_DIR/qml/Qt/labs".

Now the solution is to use QQuickWidget to be able to use QML together with the QtWidgets:

```py
import os
import sys
from pathlib import Path

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtQuickWidgets

CURRENT_DIRECTORY = Path(__file__).resolve().parent


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    label_widget = QtWidgets.QLabel("Animation", alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

    animation_widget = QtQuickWidgets.QQuickWidget(
        resizeMode=QtQuickWidgets.QQuickWidget.SizeRootObjectToView
    )
    filename = os.fspath(CURRENT_DIRECTORY / "main.qml")
    url = QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename)
    animation_widget.setSource(url)

    widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(widget)
    lay.addWidget(label_widget, stretch=0)
    lay.addWidget(animation_widget, stretch=1)
    widget.resize(640, 480)
    widget.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import Qt.labs.lottieqt 1.0

Item {
    width: 100
    height: 100
    LottieAnimation {
        anchors.fill: parent
        loops: LottieAnimation.Infinite
        source: "https://assets9.lottiefiles.com/temp/lf20_7rPCHc.json"
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]