# Missing PyQt5 binaries

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qml, lottie

When doing `pip install PyQt5` it installs PyQt5 but its missing some binaries,

what I am really looking for is the Lottie animation lib that works with QML

I'm using windows 10 64bit I been just lost looking for it.

I have used `python -m pip install aqtinstall`

and ran the command to download the binaries but those binaries don't match the QT 5.15.2 that I have, even when I specify the version in aqtinstall.

if there are any examples of how to install the right version of PyQt5 to be able to run lottie animations thro QML please share.

EDIT:

Thanks to @eyllanesc and @mugiseyebrows,

i got referred to @eyllanesc answer:  [Implementing a Lottie JSON animation into PyQt5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68429790/implementing-a-lottie-json-animation-into-pyqt5)

Although it was for linux based systems. but the aqt installer was big help.
the slight change was using windows instead of linux in the command:
`python -m aqt install 5.15.2 windows desktop win64_msvc2019_64 --outputdir -m qtlottie`

And then you would copy the `lottieqt folder` the same way @eyllanesc has Explained but then the `Qt5Bodymovin.dll` is found in the `bin folder` and You would also need to copy it into the bin folder inside the Qt5 directory.

And it works!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Implementing a Lottie JSON animation into PyQt5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68429790/implementing-a-lottie-json-animation-into-pyqt5)

Comment: yes this is good @mugiseyebrows , but unfortunately it works for linux and not windows. i tried the windows version but there are still some missing binaries.

Comment: @WalidozGal In the case of windows you must copy the .dll instead of the .so.

Comment: @eyllanesc so in this (So you should copy file "Qt/5.15.2/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Bodymovin.so.5.15.2" to "PyQt5_DIR/lib/libQt5Bodymovin.so.5" and the folder "Qt/5.15.2/gcc_64/qml/Qt/labs/lottieqt" to "PyQt5_DIR/qml/Qt/labs".) i should copy .dll from the same source and put it where exactly?

Comment: Yes my instructions were for linux, for windows you have to make those obvious changes.

Comment: there is no Bodymovin.dll in that folder that's what i mean.

Comment: sorry now i got the Bodymovin.dll, after running this command `python -m aqt install 5.15.2 windows desktop win64_msvc2019_64 --outputdir -m qtlottie` but now my issue is where do i put this file, inside the Qt5 directory there is no lib folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @eyllanesc and @mugiseyebrows,

i got referred to @eyllanesc answer: Implementing a Lottie JSON animation into PyQt5

Although it was for linux based systems. but the aqt installer was big help. the slight change was using windows instead of linux in the command: python -m aqt install 5.15.2 windows desktop win64_msvc2019_64 --outputdir -m qtlottie

And then you would copy the lottieqt folder the same way @eyllanesc has Explained but then the Qt5Bodymovin.dll is found in the bin folder and You would also need to copy it into the bin folder inside the Qt5 directory.

And it works!